# CKEditor 5 spaces Â

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have done a default CKEditor > Classic setup and implemented it with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ClassicEditor.create($('#editor')[0],{
        toolbar: ['bold','italic','paragraph'],
    });
</script>
```

However whenever I type a space " "- I end up getting a Â. Clearly this is something to do with encoding but I'm not too sure what? In my meta details I've got `<meta charset="utf-8">` but still to no avail. Is there something that needs enabling by default?

Comment: Im facing the same issue.

Comment: Ok, its wierd, i found a website that copy this website and translate to russian: http://qaru.site/questions/16453048/ckeditor-5-spaces-a

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

What about the encoding set by your server? It may serve JS files with a different encoding than UTF-8 and that causes the issue that you described.

Comment: Thanks . In my case I faced local js file itself differently encoded cause this issue. updated the ckeditor.js encoding using notpad++ editor  to UTF-8 and it works fine CKEDITOR5